# Unable to concat mp4 files using ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to combine two mp4 files without including their audio; however, despite following the formatting in many other posts, I'm unable to get my code to function.

```
//public variables


public void test(){
        String canonicalPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        String ffmpegPath="/usr/bin/local/ffmpeg";
        String vidSectPath=canonicalPath.concat("/src/Video-Sections");
        String vidPath=canonicalPath.concat("/src/Videos");
        String tempA=vidSectPath+"/Earth.mp4";
        String tempB=vidSectPath+"/Waves.mp4";
        String tempVidPath=vidPath+"/tvp.mp4";

        String[]cmd1={ffmpegPath,"-i",tempA,"-i",tempB,"-filter_complex","[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]","-map","[out]",tempVidPath};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd1);
        boolean exeCmdStatus = executeCMD(pb);
}
private boolean executeCMD(ProcessBuilder pb)
    {
     pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
     Process p = null;

     try {
      p = pb.start();

     } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println("oops");
     p.destroy();
     return false;
    }
    // wait until the process is done
    try {
     p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("woopsy");
    p.destroy();
    return false;
    }
    return true;
     }
```

I get a new mp4 file after running this code, but the mp4 file has 0 bytes and can't be opened in any media player. I've tried adding "-pix_fmt yuv420p" to cmd1, but this doesn't seem to help in any way.

I've also tried using the concat demuxer method by making the cmd1 string[] variable equal to:

```
ffmpegPath,"-f","concat","-i","-safe","0","/Users/JL/Documents/workspace/VidTest/src/concat.txt","-vcodec","copy",tempVidPath};
```

In which the content of concat.txt is

```
file '/Users/JL/Documents/workspace/VidTest/src/Video-Sections/Earth.mp4'
file '/Users/JL/Documents/workspace/VidTest/src/Video-Sections/MovWaves.mp4'
```

However, this method doesn't seem to be able to create the concatenated mp4 file.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. I'm also using a mac to execute the code.

Comment: *"I get a new mp4 file after running this code, but the mp4 file has 0 bytes"* Did you make sure the ffmpeg command runs OK in a command-line interface before adding it to your code? If yes, then show the **complete** log from the ffmpeg process.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding vsync 2, the new command is String[] cmd={"ffmpeg","-vsync","2","-i",tempPathA,"-i",tempPathB,"-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v0];[1:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[vv]","-map","[vv]",tempVidPath};